# Is $\pi_m(M) = 0$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I am doing a problem where I am stuck at this point.

> Let $M$ be a connected smooth manifold of dimension $n$ and let $X$ be any subset of $M$. Assume that there is a positive integer $m$ such that $n>2m, ~\dim X < n-m$ and $\pi_m(M-X)=0$. Then is it true that $\pi_m(M)=0$?

Here $\dim X$ is the [topological dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension) of the space $X$. If $X$ is a submanifold, I guess this result is true.

Any hint/reference will be appreciated.

Comment: If $X$ is a submanifold, you can make any map $S^m\rightarrow M$ transversal to $X$ by a homotopy, but since $m+\dim X<n$, this means it's a map $S^m\rightarrow M-X$. The claim follows from that in this case.

Comment: @Thorgott right. But for any subset do you have any idea how to do?